# Yii2 - how to properly use generatePasswordHash()?

Tags: security, hash, yii2

I'm trying to generate a random password for a user in a Yii2 application.

I have the following code:

```
$rand_password = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(8);
$user->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($rand_password);
```

After that I save the `$user` model and the hashed string is also saved in the database. However, I cannot log in with the `$rand_password` string after that as I'm getting Invalid Password error message.

The `generatePasswordHash` description says that the hash is generated from the provided password and a random salt string. Indeed, I called the function with the same password string several times in a row and I got different result every time. So my question is, if that salt string is random and different every time, how can I use this function at all to verify passwords? When I try to login I call the same function with the password string provided by the user but this time the salt will be different so I'm unable to produce the same hash as before? What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, after hours of debugging and looking for resources and explanation, it turns out the the user module I'm using: https://github.com/amnah/yii2-user is actually automatically hashing the passwords before saving them in the database. In other words, as soon as you call:

```
$user->password = SOMETHING;
```

that `SOMETHING` is automatically going through the `generatePasswordHash()` function upon save. My problem was that I was dropping it in there in my code as well so basically the password got hashed twice.